# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x195 and 128x256)

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i have a problem as my title when i run this code:

```
window = 'hann'  # window function
nperseg = 1024  # window length in samples
noverlap = 512  # overlap between windows in samples
nfft = None  # number of FFT points, default is same as nperseg

spectrogram_transform = torchaudio.transforms.Spectrogram(n_fft=nperseg, win_length=nperseg, hop_length=noverlap)
spectrogram = spectrogram_transform(resampled_waveform)
# Define the CNN model
model = nn.Sequential(
  nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),  # 32x12x12
  nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),  # 32x6x6
  nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),  # 64x6x6
  nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),  # 64x3x3
  nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),  # 128x3x3
  nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2, padding=1),  # 128x2x2
  nn.Flatten(),  # 128x4
  nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=256),  # fully connected layer with 256 output units
  nn.ReLU(),  # activation layer
  nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=80)  # fully connected layer with 80 output units (number of classes)
)

# Save the trained model
torch.save(model, 'model.pt')
model = torch.load('model.pt')
model.eval()

predictions = model(torch.from_numpy(np.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=0)).float())
```

If i change 128*4 by 195, it worked but I need to find the way to solve this completely that i can using this with many different input data

So that why i want to be clearly about my error and try to fix this. Hope that someone can help me to deal with this bug.

Answer (score 0):

update:
torch do not have global pooling, but we can implement it as

```
class GlobalAvgPooling(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=2)
        x = torch.mean(x, axis=-1)
        return x
```

Then, using this module instead of the original flatten layer as

```
model = nn.Sequential(
  nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),  # 32x12x12
  nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),  # 32x6x6
  nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),  # 64x6x6
  nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),  # 64x3x3
  nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),  # 128x3x3
  nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2, padding=1),  # 128x2x2
  GlobalAvgPooling(),  # 128, Change here
  nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=256),  # fully connected layer with 256 output units
  nn.ReLU(),  # activation layer
  nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=80)  # fully connected layer with 80 output units (number of classes)
)
```

Note that, for a 4-dims input with shape `batch, 128, 2, 2`, `nn.Flatten` will return a 2-dim tensor `batch, (128x4)`, using `start_dim` to force it keep the channel dim.

---

There is no way for the model to fit data with different lengths.
`nn.Linear` can only take input with the defined dim, but the previous layer is `nn.flaten`, which will change the dim according to the inputs' width and height.
A simple way is to use global pooling to reduce the width and height dims.

Comment: Could you specify more how to use global pooling to solve this problem

Comment: code in comment may looks bad, so I edit the answer.